# Limit search to specific document type

Tags: solr, solrnet

Let's say I have one collection that contain two document types: product and customer.
Now I would like to search for a certain text in the customer document type.

How should I do this in Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at filter queries, http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq e.g.

```
http://solr_url:solr_port/solr/select?q=text_you_are_looking_for&fq=document_type:customer
```

Comment: So I should add a new field document_type that contains the document type?

Comment: Yes, you will need to field to identify document type.